# How to make isTextSearchEnabled property work in case of ComboBox with icons in the beginning of text?

Tags: xaml, uwp, combobox, windows-10, c++-cx

In a ComboBox, we can jump to an item by typing its first few letters. This is when `IsTextSearchEnabled` property is set, which by default is true.

I have a custom ComboBox with images in the beginning, followed by a short text.

```
icon1 + Violet
icon2 + Red
icon3 + Blue
```

If I type "r", I expect to navigate to the `Red` item in the dropdown. However, because of an icon in the beginning, the `IsTextSearchEnabled` property does not behave as expected.

How can I make this work?

For example, in `MyDropdown.cpp`, I have

```
MyDropDownItem^ comboItem = ref new MyDropDownItem(icon, title);
sourceItems->Append(comboItem);
```

`sourceItems` is the list of items that the ItemsSource of this control uses. Each combobox item has a different image(icon) and hence, image src cannot be statically defined in xaml template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make isTextEnabled property work in case of ComboBox with icons in the beginning of text?

You could bind ComboBox `ItemsSource` with string collection then custom the item content like the following, when you typing text, it will match with `ItemsSource`.

```
<ComboBox
    x:Name="MyComboBox"
    Width="200"
    Header="Colors"
    IsEditable="True"
    Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded"     
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image
                    Width="22"
                    Height="22"
                    Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                    />
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="10"
                    Text="{Binding}"
                    TextAlignment="Center"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyComboBox.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
}
```

**Update**

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string resaut = string.Empty;
        switch (value.ToString())
        {
            case "Blue":
                resaut = "ms-appx:///Assets/BlueImage.png";
                break;
            case "Green":
                resaut = "ms-appx:///Assets/GreenImage.png";
                break;
            case "Red":
                resaut = "ms-appx:///Assets/RedImage.png";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return resaut;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image
                Width="22"
                Height="22"
                Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Margin="10"
                Text="{Binding}"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question. In my custom dropdown, images are not constant. The approach we're using right now is to append image and text together as an object in the itemsSource. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Yep,  The above code is for testing only, for the specific scenario we need use [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter) to make color string to image uri.

Comment: I have update the answer with complete code please check. @zazky

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and also for pointing me to converters :)