# UWP ComboBox IsEditable does not work right

Tags: c#, uwp, combobox

this is my code, The combo-box control contains text & image :

XAML codes :

```
<ComboBox Name="cb1"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          Header="Abcd"
          IsEditable="True"
          Margin="5"
          Width="120">

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5,0,10,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

C# codes :

```
public sealed partial class SamplePage2 : Page
{
    public SamplePage2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cb1.Items.Add(new Model
        {
            Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/mecca.png")),
            Text = "بقره"
        });

        cb1.Items.Add(new Model
        {
            Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/medina.png")),
            Text = "فاتحه"
        });

        cb1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    class Model
    {
        public BitmapImage Icon { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But when I click on the pointer button, or click inside the text..., see this image :

[image]

How I can solve this problem?

Note : I need 'IsEditable' feature [ Because I want the user to quickly reach the desired option by writing the text. ]

Comment: Have you tried overriding ToString on your custom elements?

Comment: I edit my post, please see again, 'Text Property' is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP ComboBox IsEditable does not work right

The problem is the display member is the model class, so it will not editable, for your scenario, we suggest you make a string collection as ComboBox data source. Then us image converter to set image source base on the item's content. For more please refer this case [reply](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264258/7254781).

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image
                Width="22"
                Height="22"
                Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"
                />
            <TextBlock
                Margin="10"
                Text="{Binding}"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyComboBox.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
}
```

**Image Converter**

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string resaut = string.Empty;
        switch (value.ToString())
        {
            case "Blue":
                resaut = "ms-appx:///Assets/BlueImage.png";
                break;
            case "Green":
                resaut = "ms-appx:///Assets/GreenImage.png";
                break;
            case "Red":
                resaut = "ms-appx:///Assets/RedImage.png";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return resaut;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```